# How to proof or derive that the central charge in Virasoro algebra for boson and fermion were $1$ and $\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

How to proof or derive that the central charge in Virasoro algebra for boson and fermion were $1$ and $\frac{1}{2}$? Further, how to show that $n$ copies of bosons or fermions(with generator $a^\mu_n$ and $b^\nu_m$ respectively) simply add the central charge to be $n$ or $\frac{n}{2}$?

For simplicity one could assume the simple bulk (entire complex plane) theory.

Comment: Compute $\langle TT\rangle$ in the theories of interest. It is also easy to see that it is additive when you take decoupled theories together.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk  But from the view of Virsoro algebra, there's only $L_n$, not $L^\mu_n$. There's not a way to go up from the algebra itself and no involve the OPE?

Comment: Because though with the algebra being a way of representing the stress tensor, the properties were carried along. But the algebra were generators, the stress tensor could also be represented by the algebra, and it's not obvious from there. Especially, none of the books I saw showed how exactly central charges were added. Especially, what if $g_{\mu\nu}$ were no longer diagonal?

Answer (score 1):

With $N$ decoupled theories, you do have a separate Virasoro algebra for each copy.
$$
[L_m^i, L_n^j] = \delta^{ij} \left ( (m - n)L^i_{m + n} + \frac{c^i}{12}n(n^2-1) \delta_{m+n,0} \right )
$$
The stress tensor people refer to when they talk about "the" central charge is the sum of the individual stress tensors. Therefore,
\begin{align}
[l_m, L_n] &= \sum_{i = 1}^N \sum_{j = 1}^N [L^i_m, L^j_n] \\
&= (m - n) \sum_{i = 1}^N L^i_{m + n} + \frac{1}{12}n(n^2-1)\delta_{m+n,0} \sum_{i = 1}^N c^i
\end{align}
and we read off the central charge as being the sum.